# "Flask ImportError: No Module Named Flask" in ./test.py

Tags: flask, microservices, devops, python-3.8

I tried to write a microservice as below structure but when I run ./test.py I got error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from authorize import create_app
  File "~/projects/authorize/authorize/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

My project structure:

```
authorize
├── authorize
│   ├── config
│   │   ├── config.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.py
├── test.py
```

Each files in my project is:

/authorize/test.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from authorize import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

/authorize/authorize/__init__.py:

```
from flask import Flask

from authorize.config import Config

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)   
    return app
```

/authorize/authorize/config/__init__.py:

```
from authorize.config.config import Config
```

/authorize/authorize/config/config.py:

```
from os import environ

class Config:

    ENV = environ.get("MY_AUTH_ENV", "production")
    DEBUG = int(environ.get("MY_AUTH_DEBUG","0"))
    TESTING = int(environ.get("MY_AUTH_TESTING", "0"))
```

I isolated my project in venv and the requirements packages are:

```
click==8.0.1
Flask==2.0.1
itsdangerous==2.0.1
Jinja2==3.0.1
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
pkg_resources==0.0.0
python-dotenv==0.19.0
simplejson==3.17.3
watchdog==2.1.3
Werkzeug==2.0.1
```

I will appretiate for your helps.

Comment: What's the result of `pip freeze | grep -i flask` command?

Comment: It's Flask==2.0.1

Answer (score 1):

I found that I can use :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

instead of

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

in file test.py and it works.

but still I have one problem, below code in authorize/authorize/__init__.py get my environment variables but can't change my "app" configs:

```
app.config.from_object(Config)   # Load configs from env variables
```